# Toggle visibility of table columns without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html-table, toggle, visibility

I have a multi-column HTML table where I would like to toggle the visibility of a given column (below, the 4th). I've successfully implemented this in jQuery as follows:

```
document.write('<a class="toggle" href="#!" data-alt="Hide">Show</a>.');
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var curr = el.text();
        el.text(el.attr("data-alt"));
        el.attr("data-alt", curr);
        $('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').toggle();
    });
});
```

However, I'd like to implement this in pure Javascript as this is the only function on my site which uses jQuery. I've struggled as the solutions I've seen to this use `getElementsByClassName` and `classList.toggle()` which won't work for me as I can't add attributes to all `td` and `th` elements (my HTML is generated by a Markdown implementation which can't do that).

I suspect that maybe there's a solution using `document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(x)')` but I haven't figured it out. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In JavaScript you can use the `document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(x)')` statement to implement a solution for your problem.

You will also need to implement an additional function to toggle the visibility of the elements. See the code below.

```
var toggleDisplay = function (element) {
  element.style.display = (element.style.display === 'none')?'block':'none';
};
```

Now, you can call the below statement to toggle visibility of a column.

```
document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(x),th:nth-child(x)').forEach(toggleDisplay);
```

Make sure to replace 'x' with your column number.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else, to implement [Vivek's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47881579/2336845) and add the original text swapping, I used `<input>` + `<label>` instead of `<a>`:

```
var message = '<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">\
    <label for="checkbox" id="clickme" onclick="toggle()"></label>.';

document.write(message);

var toggleDisplay = function (element) {
  element.style.display = (element.style.display === 'none')?'block':'none';
};

function toggle() {
    document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').forEach(toggleDisplay);
};
```

and then used CSS to add the text:

```
#checkbox {
    display: none;
}

#checkbox:not(:checked) + #clickme:after {
    content: "Show";
}

#checkbox:checked + #clickme:after {
    content: "Hide";
}
```

Lots of ways to skin that cat but that seems most straightforward to me. Thanks so much!